# Update exiting element ng-repeat list in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made  task table through the **ng-repeat**, Each task in table can can be modify. Task table will have to updated with updated task. So for this we need to access particular ng-repeat element. I want to know how to access particular ng-repeat element and update this with new task **ng-click=editTask()**.

**Please see  `$scope.editTask`, Here I want to update inside  `$http.put(uri, data)`.**

**Workflow:**

ng-click=beginTask(task) opens dialog, In dialog there is ng-click=editTask(), which will modify the task through $http.put...
Please see [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gftTKZqLk3LPgrhgqz2A?p=preview)

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks"> 
      <td>{{task.title}}</td>
      <td>{{task.description}}</td>
      <td>
         <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="beginEdit(task)">Edit</a>
      </td>      
 </tr>
```

**Angularjs code**

```
$scope.beginEdit=function(task){
      $scope.title = task.title; 
      $scope.description=task.description;
      $scope.done=task.done;
      $scope.uri=task.uri;
      $scope.index=$scope.tasks.indexOf(task);            
             $('#edit').modal('show');

        };

        $scope.editTask = function() {   
             title=$scope.title;
             description=$scope.description;
             done=$scope.done;
             uri=$scope.uri;
             $('#edit').modal('hide');                 
             var i=$scope.index;
             var data={title: title, description: description, done: done };               

             $http.put(uri, data)
             .success(function(){
                 alert("Success");
             });                 
        };
```

Comment: You are passing the `task` to the `beginEdit()` function. Store this task in a scope / local variable so that when `editTask` is called, it knows which task to edit using the earlier stored scope / local variable.

Comment: @callmekatootie  Thanks for reply, task can be access through $scope.tasks.indexof(task), no problem in this but my question is how to update particular ng-repeat element ......

Comment: Don't use jQuery modal. Use AngularUI bootstrap. Then remove beginEdit and use just editTask with task object passed in it. From there open `$modal.open(...)` modal with cloned scope tasks data. Using promise then update existing task object which is still in the scope.

Comment: @dfsq thanks for reply It is possible give more detail on this or suggest some links...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this - : http://plnkr.co/edit/lVkWEsAGVLTY7mGfHP5N?p=preview

Add

```
$scope.tasks[$scope.index] = data;
```

In editTask

```
$scope.editTask = function(obj) {
    alert($scope.title);
    title = $scope.title;
    description = $scope.description;
    done = $scope.done;
    uri = $scope.uri;
    $('#edit').modal('hide');

    var i = $scope.index;
    var data = {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        done: done
    };
    alert("uri" + uri);
    alert(data.title);
    $scope.tasks[$scope.index] = data; // For updating value
    $http.put(uri, data)
        .success(function() {
            //tasks[i].uri(data.uri);  

            alert("Success");
        });

};
```

Comment: Just one more question I put `$scope.tasks[$scope.index] = data; ` inside the .success, and if we modify the task and reload the browser it retains the update, Why it is workinng same when we put out side of $http.put.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more. Not getting your question.